# "PolyglotException" error when the karate assertion (on a JSON object) contains a tag with whitespace

Tags: karate

My response is a JSON object with nested arrays, as you can see below:

`16:15:20.461 [print] {"Successful Requests":[{"Status":201,"Resource ID":2373202,"Message":"Created resource 1 at URI: /ids/2373202"},{"Status":201,"Resource ID":2373268,"Message":"Created resource 2 at URI: /ids/2373268"},{"Status":201,"Resource ID":2373334,"Message":"Created resource 3 at URI: /ids/2373334"}],"Failed Requests":[]}`

I would like to do an assertion to make sure the first array (i.e., "**Successful Requests**") contains 3 objects, and that the second array (i.e., "**Failed Requests**") is null.

I've tried:

`And match response."Successful Requests" == '#[3]'`

But I got the following error, which I am assuming is due to the tag having a whitespace.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS0ve.png)

___

My first idea was to make the assertion using the schema validation, so:

```
And match response ==
    """
    {
        "Successful Requests": [
            {
                "Status": 201,
                "Resource ID": #number,
                "Message": "Created resource 1 at URI: /#number"
            },
            {
                "Status": 201,
                "Resource ID": #number,
                "Message": "Created resource 2 at URI: /#number"
            },
            {
                "Status": 201,
                "Resource ID": #number,
                "Message": "Created resource 3 at URI: /#number"
            }
        ],
        "Failed Requests": []
    }
    """
```

But I got the following error:

[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbeBI.png)

I'm new on Karate, still learning how to use it, and the best practices, but I got stuck on this test and decided to ask someone else's opinion about the most convenient assertion for my scenario. Feedback is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have spaces or special characters, refer to nested elements using the square-bracket notation. For example:

```
* match response['Successful Requests'] == '#[3]'
* match response['Failed Requests'] == '#[0]'
```

Comment: If we need to fetch the value of the Resource ID attribute from the first object then what will be the syntax? Can you let me know. I tried below syntax but it did not work.                                                                                                                    * print request1["Successful Requests"][0].["Resource ID"]

Comment: no idea, it should have worked. if stuck, follow the process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue